# Видимость вложенного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть класс List и вложенный класс Node(на методы и поля не обращайте внимания)

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List();

    void push_back(T data);
    void lin();

    int size() { return Size; }

    T& operator[](const int index);
private:
    template<typename T>
    class Node {
    public:
        Node* pNext;
        T data;
        Node(T data = T(), Node* pNext = nullptr) {
            this->data = data;
            this->pNext = pNext;
        }
    };
    int Size;
    Node<T>* Top;
};
```

Я создаю функцию firstTask и хочу создать указатель типа Node

```
void firstTask(List<T>list1, List<T>list2) {
    List<T> temp;
    temp = list1;
    Node* P1 = list1.Top;
}
```

Но функция не видит этот класс. Как мне сделать его видимым?

Comment: А у вас нет никакого класса `Node`, есть класс `List<T>::Node<T2>`. Ну и тут `Node` явно должен быть без параметров, ведь тип T в нем может браться из внешнего класса.

Comment: Нет смысла делать `class Node` шаблоном, уберите `template<typename T>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
typename List<T>::Node* P1 = list1.Top;
```

Только у вас `Node` - он таки шаблонный или нет? Т.е. может ли внутри `List<int>` быть, скажем, `Node<double>`? Если нет - не нужно его делать шаблоном внутри шаблона.

Comment: Спасибо! Но зачем здесь typename используется?

Comment: Чтобы пояснить, что `Node` - это именно тип, а не, скажем, поле класса `List<T>` - мало ли чем этот `Node` может быть...

Comment: `typename` тут не нужно, так как в приведенном примере `Node` не является зависимым именем, ведь `firstTask` - не шаблон. А конструкция `List<T>::Node` все равно работать не будет, так как пропущены параметры шаблона `Node`. Да и вообще этот ответ лучше был бы комментарием.

Comment: @user7860670 `firstTask` не может не быть шаблоном - с его аргументом `List<T>`. Скорее всего ТС просто опустил `template<typename T>.